# angularjs weird error loading controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, controller, ionic-framework

I've being developing angularjs for the last months and I have an app with some controllers, directives and services. Until now all have gone all right, but with the last controller I'm getting a weird error that it's making me go mad. Because the app its a bigger enough to put here all code I will put the important parts.

In my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="my_app">
<head>
    <meta charset="encoding">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <meta name="viewport"  content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <!--<script src=""-->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>


    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!--SERVICES-->
    <script src="js/services/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/s_configDB.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/s_clinicDB.js"></script>
    <!-- CONTROLLERS -->
    <script src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/c_splash.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/c_communications.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/controllers/c_communicationsB.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/controllers/c_clock.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/c_menu.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/c_language.js"></script>
    <!--DIRECTIVES-->
    <script src="js/directives/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives/d_menu.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="AppComms">
    <ion-nav-view ></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>

At my app.js:

var SDv4 = angular.module('my_app', [
    'ionic',
    'my_app.services',
    'my_app.controllers',
    'my_app.directives'
]);
```

At controllers.js

```
var app = angular.module('my_app.controllers',[
    //'ionic',
    'my_app.c_splash',
    'my_app.c_clock',
    'my_app.c_language',
    'my_app.c_comms',
    //'my_app.c_commsb',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'my_app.c_menu'
]);
```

And for example the c_communications.js

```
var comms = angular.module('my_app.c_comms',[])

comms.controller('AppComms',['$scope',function($scope){

    …

}])
```

This code is working ok, but if I add another controller (c_communicationsB.js) :

```
var commsb = angular.module('my_app.c_commsb',[])
```

and add the my_app.commsb to the controllers.js

It gives me the error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:8895 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MY_APP due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module my_app.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module my_app.c_commsb due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module ‘my_app.c_commsb' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=MY_APP.c_commsb
    at http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8895:12
    at http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10785:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10709:38)
    at module (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10783:14)
    at http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13189:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
    at http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13190:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=MY_APP.c_commsb&…3A63342%2FSD4v040t2%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13173%3A5)
    at http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8895:12
    at http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13212:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
    at http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13190:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
    at http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13190:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=MY_APP.controlle…3A63342%2FSD4v040t2%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13173%3A5)
    at http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8895:12
    at http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13212:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
    at http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13190:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13099:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10457:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:63342/SD4v040t2/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10478:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=MY_APP&p1=Error%…A63342%2FSD4v040t2%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A10478%3A12)
```

What is happening here?!

Comment: the comments of communicationsB.js and the my_app.commsb is for showing what is the new code but when I get the error is not commented, sorry if it was missunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

a week ago I used a script to prevent loading page from cache in browser in order to no need to refresh the site when i was debugging on chrome and force always to read from source.

I don't know who or why it was preventing of loading new controllers or new css in a new html  page I've added, this is what has made me think about this script.

Answer (score 0):

you have commented out the line `<!--<script src="js/controllers/c_communicationsB.js"></script>`

in your code sample, but have said that the method is in here.

Comment: yes, it's not commented when I have the error, the comments. you can see in controllers.js also is commented, I've done like this for explain what was the code working

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your app is not getting called. Try wrapping your app in an IFFY.

```
(function () {
    var comms = angular.module('my_app.c_comms',[]);

    comms.controller('AppComms',['$scope',function($scope){
        //controller magic here
    }])

}());
```

This is a self calling function so your app will get called by itself.

Comment: but all my other controllers aren't wrapped in a IFFY function, I prefer not to use them

Answer (score 0):

//At controllers.js

```
angular.module('my_app',[
    //'ionic',
    'my_app.c_splash',
    'my_app.c_clock',
    'my_app.c_language',
    'my_app.c_comms',
    //'my_app.c_commsb',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'my_app.c_menu'
]);
```

Comment: I call my_app.controller from app.js so I cant erase controllers from here, I have tried and it doesn't load nothing but with no errors

Comment: Are you loading them in the correct order? If you haven't loaded a module that this controller relies on first then it will fail